# Importing Debian Bugs to Launchpad

Tags: ubuntu, debian, bugzilla, launchpad

While reading about how the bugs from debian are imported to launchpad, I came across a blueprint https://blueprints.launchpad.net/launchpad/+spec/debian-bug-import which was used initially to import bugs from debian. I cannot find the script that was used to import them or the logic that was used. Did the people import all the bugs from debian or did they filter the bugs. And how are the bugs presently imported from debian to launchpad. I came across a script in launchpad which imports bugs from debian given certain bug numbers but I wanted to know whether there is some automation that exists for importing relevant debian bugs to launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any automation here; Debian bugs aren't automatically imported into Launchpad. However, if you specify the Debain bug number in a Launchpad bug, then the Debian bug status is tracked in Launchpad.

Comment: "Tracking" is distinct from "importing", though.